# how to get long press event of textfield in codename one

Tags: textfield, codenameone, long-press

I am developing in Codename One.

I am having TextField in one form.

I want to open a dialog box on TextField's long press event

So how can I get **long press event of TextField in codename one** ?

I already tried by impementing ActionEvent and checked with

```
if(event.isLongEvent()){

}
```

but its not working..

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.
Akash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since text field uses native editing the long press event will be grabbed by the native editing functionality so for the text field it just won't work well.

You can derive most components and override `longPress` or add a long press listener to the form which will have a similar effect but its likely to cause an issue with the native input.

Comment: I tried by adding
`findPOnumber().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.isLongEvent()){
      Dialog.show("Long","Long Pressed..!", "Ok", null);
    }
  }
});`

its not working I also tried by adding event to form

`f.addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  Log.p("form actionPerformed... ");
   if(evt.isLongEvent()){
     Dialog.show("Long","Long Press","Ok",null);
   }
  }
});`

Still its not working can you give me some example?
FYI:I am new to CodenameOne
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one works :

```
Button button = new Button("Test") {
    @Override
    public void longPointerPress(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("LONG PRESS");

    }
};
```