# How to have a longPress Event on a CheckBox in Codenameone?

Tags: android, ios, checkbox, codenameone, long-press

i need to implement a long press event on a checkbox in codenameone.
On normal buttons i use the longPointerPress method and a boolean to control if the short- or longpress event happens.
With the checkboxes i cannot find that option, it only toggles between checked/unchecked.

How is it possible to use a long press on a checkbox?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with codenameone, but in Android you can just use [setOnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)) since every View has that function.

Answer (score 0):

`longPress` is a callback. You don't invoke it, you override it and it triggers when a longpress occurs. So Codename One invokes it internally. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54063388/756809